# Can Summernote editor produce XHTML code?

Tags: html, xhtml, summernote

I'd like to use the [Summoernote](http://summernote.org) editor as alternative to the currently used TinyMCE, but it is a requirement to produce XHTML code.

Per default, it writes HTML5 code, f.i.:

```
<p>Foo<br>bar<br></p><hr><p>Baz<br></p>
```

What I would like to get is this:

```
<p>Foo<br />bar<br /></p><hr /><p>Baz<br /></p>
```

I can't find any reference to it, but can summernote somehow output XHTML code by a plugin or other means?

Comment: I would assume that it would output XHTML by default if it was running in an XHTML document (due to how browsers handle content editable areas) … but it won't run in one of those and aborts with — *Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.* — frankly, in 2015 a requirement for XHTML is pretty odd. It's pretty much dead.

Comment: @Quentin Don't systems like JSF output XHTML by default?

Comment: @MrLister — I have no idea, but the well formedness requirements are still more trouble then they are worth for the benefits XML brings (no benefit at all in most cases).

Comment: The thing is, the output must pass a legacy serverside validator, that parses XML, so HTML5 is seen as invalid and all tags are stripped.

Comment: @Quentin: The installation of summernote states that it "Requires HTML5 doctype". So it's ok that it fails in XHTML environment. :)

Comment: HTML 5 includes an XML serialisation. The test document I used had an HTML 5 Doctype (although with an application/xhtml+xml content type) and it caused jQuery to throw the above error message.